# How to display Shortcode hook functions output at the end of post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I have made a shortcode hook with twitter button api.When i use the shortcode in any post after the image or content, the button displaying at top of the post.how can i display the button below the image or content of the post.

Here is the Code to figure out.

```
function twittershare()
{
    ?>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-url="<?php echo get_option('option1'); ?>" data-via="<?php echo get_option('option2');?>" data-text="<?php echo get_option('option3'); ?>" data-count="<?php echo get_option('option4'); ?>" data-lang="<?php echo get_option('option5'); ?>" data-counturl="<?php echo get_option('option1'); ?>" >Tweet</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    <?php
}
```

Following is the shortcode i have created.

```
add_shortcode('share',array('SampleTwitterShare','twittershare'));
```

where:

- `Share` is the shortcode.
- `SampleTwitterShare` is the class
  name.
- `twittershare` is the function with twitter share API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to (concatenate and) **return** the HTML in your shortcode callback function, e.g.:

```
function twittershare()
{
    $html = '';

    $html .= '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-url="' . get_option('option1') . '" data-via="' . get_option('option2') . '" data-text="' . get_option('option3') . '" data-count="' . get_option('option4') . '" data-lang="' . get_option('option5') . '" data-counturl="' . get_option('option1') . '" >Tweet</a>';
    $html .= '<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie to php.i used twitter stuff outside the php tags,so how can i save output to a variable and return it.